# How to properly add a new code segment in IDA?

Tags: assembly, binary, exe, reverse-engineering, ida

I'd like to modify (patch) some binary using `IDA` (PRO 7.5 SP3). I've added a new `segment` for my new code, implemented some function there and when i select "`Apply patches to input file...`" i get this ugly errors:

```
40400D: has no file mapping (original: FF patched: 55)...skipping...
40400E: has no file mapping (original: FF patched: 89)...skipping...
40400F: has no file mapping (original: FF patched: E5)...skipping...
404010: has no file mapping (original: FF patched: 6A)...skipping...
...
```

I'm attaching the segments view below: [image]

What is the reason for that and what to do to make it work?

Thx for help!

Comment: You don't want a new segment. You want to extend the size of the existing `.text` segment. Existing code jumping into your new segment will cause a Segmentation Fault.