# Find a free space in dissembled PE

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, portable-executable, ida

I've dissembled some `PE` using `IDA` (PRO 7.5 SP3). Now i'd like to add some new code there (using `patching`). The question is how can i find some free space in this dissembled code to utilize it?

Comment: "Free space" is too broad of a term. File formats are optimized to not include unnecessary space. In the PE file format, each segment of code is defined to have a length. The `.text` segment typically starts before the other ones. So adding to the end of the `.text` segment would likely begin to overwrite adjacent segments. You can change the existing bytes at your own risk. If you want to _add bytes_, you need to resize the `.text` segment and adjust the headers and segment information accordingly, which is much more hands on.

Comment: @h0r53. Ok i understand. I've tried to add a whole new segment using IDA, but when i click to apply patches i made (new instructions added in this new segment) i gen an ugly errors "404004: has no file mapping" and so on. Look also on my question about that: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762167/how-to-properly-add-a-new-code-segment-in-ida). Maybe You can help me with this problem?

Comment: How large is the part you want to patch in? If it's quite small you may be able to put it after a `ret` somewhere. Function starts are usually aligned to at least 4 or 16 bytes boundaries.